# Linq Extension Methods Not available in Visual Studio 2015 Immediate Window

Tags: c#, visual-studio, linq, visual-studio-2015

> error CS1061: 'ICollection<>' does not contain a definition for 'SelectMany' and no extension method 'SelectMany' accepting a first argument of type 'ICollection<>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Visual Studio 2015 supports evaluating linq lambda expressions in debug mode, in immediate window. I have tested it with a console application wherein i fetch `Process.GetProcesses()`, go to immediate window and start writing `.Select` or `.Where` on it. It works fine.

However, I am not able to do the same in my Project.

My Breakpoint is at this line:

```
return Dimensions.Values.SelectMany(dimension => dimension.Attributes)
                        .FirstOrDefault(dimensionAttribute => key.Equals(dimensionAttribute.Key));
```

**Doing a F10 works**. However when I try to run this same expression in parts, in immediate window i.e. `Dimensions.Values.SelectMany(dimension => dimension.Attributes)`, I get the above mentioned error.

Am I trying to evaluate this in an incorrect manner? What am I missing?

Comment: Just to be sure.. Are you sure you have `using Systen.Linq`?

Comment: Are you using System.Linq?

Comment: @GiladGreen, @mww, yes i am using `System.Linq`. I must tell you its outside `namespace {}` and on top of it. I mentioned this because i wanted to explicitly tell that its not inside `namespace {}`  .  Also, F10 is working.

Comment: try to include `System.Data.Entity` dll reference into your project, may be solve your issue !

Comment: Strange, this is working today!! Not sure about the intermittent behavior.

Comment: I remember reading somewhere, it has something to do with pdb files and lost symbols. I am not sure but will things work fine if i delete the pdb files and debug again. Ill post my findings next time i encounter the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I can't give you the reason why that happens (I have similar issues with the Immediate Window), but I found that you can call extension methods via static class access. In your case that would be:

```
Enumerable.FirstOrDefault(Enumerable.SelectMany(Dimensions.Values, dimension => dimension.Attributes),dimensionAttribute => key.Equals(dimensionAttribute.Key));
```

Comment: Dang this is awesome and hacky. I love it.

Comment: Thanks @Lennart, This works! I needed something like this for immediate purpose, i can sail through a little longer. But, i cannot accept this as an answer for the specific question i asked. The reason we use extension methods is so that we can chain them. Was it this way that its supposed to work in vs 2015 immediate window?

Comment: @singsuyash Be aware that you could be calling different extension methods. The real code might be an `IQueryable<T>`, which has different extension methods.